# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken in Laravel 5.1 + angular

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel-5.1, csrf

I have Laravel 5.1 + angular form sending JSON request when user want to send mail from website feedback form.

I did my form according to documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf  and anyway I get error message `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`

I found a lot of topics on stackoverflow, but no real solution. 
Is there?

in header of my layout I have

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```

then in my form I have this

```
        <form name="callback" ng-controller="callbackController" role="form" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
    ...
    ...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="submit(callback.$valid)" ng-bind="submittext" ng-class="{ 'btn-danger': callback.name.$touched && callback.name.$invalid || callback.tel.$touched && callback.tel.$invalid, 'btn-success': callback.name.$touched && callback.name.$valid && callback.tel.$touched && callback.tel.$valid, }">Send</button>

    </form>
```

here is the code of my angular

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngMessages', 'angularFileUpload'])

  .controller('callbackController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.url = '/';
    $scope.submittext = 'Отправить';

    $scope.submit = function(isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
          $scope.submittext = 'Отправляем...';
          $http.post($scope.url, 
            {
              "formname": "callback", 
              "name": $scope.name, 
              "tel": $scope.tel, 
              "time": $scope.time, 
              "email": $scope.email, 
              "msg": $scope.msg
            }).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data;
                        });
              $timeout(function() {  
                $('#callback').modal('hide');
                $scope.submittext = 'Отправить';
                $scope.name = null;
                $scope.tel = null;
                $scope.time = null;
                $scope.email = null;
                $scope.msg = null;
                $scope.callback.$setPristine();
                $scope.callback.$setUntouched();
              },    1000);

      } else {
              $('.errors').modal('show');
            }

        }

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the second line in the form

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

generates some code like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="ZwiQQ3BJFbWMr4goixtcklwGvpxIeN8vkWNinHIL">
```

which is not what you need.

Just like the link you have posted, you need to put the following line in the head area:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

because using ajax, you are adding a header which picks its value by looking for a meta tag which has the name `csrf-token`

Comment: maybe I need to edit something in my angular module? Because actually I have nothing there, which interacting with csrf token